# AWS EC2 Load Balancing: point to specific AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I'm using the EC2 load balancer. Since I'm implementing my own autoscaling policy, I will not use to auto scaling EC2 service that I imagine is well integrated with the Load Balancer. Basically I will scale out istances all from the same AMI. I notice that the load balancer ask to specify all the instances ids whose workload have to be balanced. My question is: it is possible to instruct the load balancer to automatically distribute the workload among all the instances belonging to a given AMI? In this way every time my scaling system scale out an instance of the given AMI, I don't need to add the new instance to the load balancer configuration. I search about this on google, but I didn't find any useful information. There is maybe something I'm misunderstanding about the load balancer usage? Because to me it seems to be a quite common feature a load balancer should have. Maybe apply balancing over a given AMI would cause some problems I cannot see? Thank you all in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AMI is just an operating system image, and has no relationship to load balancers. There is no feature that will automatically add new instances of a particular AMI and join them to an ELB.

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to use [EC2 User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) and the [AWS CLI tool](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to [add the instance to the ELB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_DeReg_Reg_Instances.html) when it first boots.

But I have to ask - why not use the native AWS autoscaling feature? It's actually quite flexible and is integrated with cloudwatch so there's a lot less you have to build yourself.

Comment: +1 - Don't bother building an autoscaling function yourself. AWS built-in autoscaling more than has this covered.

Comment: yes guys, I agree with you, but actually it is my master thesis and I have to do it LOL. Moreover it will act as the autoscaling reasoner of a more complex multicloud infrastructure, so it has an its own life. Anyway thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: If you dont want to use scaling policies in AWS autoscaling and have your own application doing scale up/down decisions you can have it call the autoscaling API to set the desired number of instances on your autoscaling group.

Comment: Even in this case I have to user CloudML (from SINTEF) to scale in/out since I need an abstraction from scaling in different Cloud providers. But about the autoscaling group concept I was thinking at the following idea: it is possible do the following?

1)create an autoscaling group of instances
2)set a load balancer to manager all the instances in a given autoscaling group
3) add an instance to the group instead of to the load balancer after the scale out